# How to display down/ up arrow based on selection on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to change the **up/down arrow** based on selection. If dropdown is open arrow should point up and if it's closed arrow should point down. I'm also trying to move the **"clear" icon** to the left of the arrow icon (currently it shows on the right). Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please see attached pictures:

Here's my  [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7hgum-hhpcej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedFood" disableOptionCentering panelClass="dva-mat-select-container">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of foods" [value]="item.value">
        {{ item.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <button mat-button matSuffix *ngIf="selectedFood" mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
    (click)="onClick($event)">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Custom Open/Closed Icons**

> Hide the existing CSS based arrows and replace them with our own custom icons. Use the select list open state to determine which icon to display

1. hide the existing arrows.

```css
      :host mat-select ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
        border: 0;
      }

      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused.mat-primary .mat-select-arrow 
      {
        border: 0;
      }
```

2. Keep track of the select open state

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedFood" openedChange)="handleOpenChange()">
```

```js
panelIsOpen: boolean = false;

handleOpenChange() {
  this.panelIsOpen = !this.panelIsOpen;
}
```

3. Display appropriate icon

```html
<mat-icon class="my-icon" *ngIf="panelIsOpen">arrow_circle_down</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="my-icon" *ngIf="!panelIsOpen">arrow_circle_up</mat-icon>
```

**Move the clear button**

> Create a wrapper for the clear button & up/down buttons so we can use CSS to arrange them

1. Wrap the buttons in a div and use class my-suffix to style it

```html
    <div matSuffix class="my-suffix">
        <button  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
    (click)="onClick($event)">
      <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
  </button>
        <mat-icon class="my-icon" *ngIf="panelIsOpen">arrow_circle_down</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="my-icon" *ngIf="!panelIsOpen">arrow_circle_up</mat-icon>
    </div>
```

2. Style the wrapper

```css
   .my-suffix {
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
      }
```

3. Control the visibility of the clear button. Note ngIf is not used, since this will insert/remove the button in the DOM and cause the select to change size as it is inserted /removed.

```html
    <button  matSuffix [style.visibility]="!selectedFood? 'hidden': 'visible'" mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
    (click)="onClick($event)">
      <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7hgum-yc9cc8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

And full code in case link expires in the future

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: "select-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "select-overview-example.html",
  styles: [
    `
      :host mat-select ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
        border: 0;
      }

      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused.mat-primary .mat-select-arrow {
        border: 0;
      }

      .my-suffix {
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  selectedFood: string;

  panelIsOpen: boolean = false;

  handleOpen() {
    this.panelIsOpen = !this.panelIsOpen;
  }

  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: "steak-0", viewValue: "item 1" },
    { value: "pizza-1", viewValue: "item 2" },
    { value: "tacos-21", viewValue: "item 3" },
    { value: "tacos-22", viewValue: "item 4" },
    { value: "tacos-23", viewValue: "item 5" },
    { value: "tacos-24", viewValue: "item 6" },
    { value: "tacos-25", viewValue: "item 7" }
  ];

  onClick(event: any) {
    this.selectedFood = "";
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedFood" disableOptionCentering panelClass="dva-mat-select-container"
        (openedChange)="handleOpen()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of foods" [value]="item.value">
            {{ item.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <div matSuffix class="my-suffix">
        <button  matSuffix [style.visibility]="!selectedFood? 'hidden': 'visible'" mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
    (click)="onClick($event)">
      <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
  </button>
        <mat-icon class="my-icon" *ngIf="panelIsOpen">arrow_circle_down</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="my-icon" *ngIf="!panelIsOpen">arrow_circle_up</mat-icon>
    </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work when you select an option (if the user selects an option I'm expecting to show the down arrow, but it looks like your answer requires to not focus on the element for this to happen). Also, I would like to override the arrow with the arrows I provided in my pictures

Comment: your answer is also getting the item id, not it's value selected when trying to use mat-select-trigger

Comment: Hey @progx, yes I was aware it displayed the ID and not the value; I mentioned that in my original answer. That said I had some spare time today so have updated the answer and provided a working example that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the javascript query selector.  Add an event on mat-select for open/close or like toggle event.

To catch that specific icon, also put a custom class on the mat-select field like 'my-select'.

```
<mat-select class="my-select" />
```

**when the dropdown state is open do this:**

```
var dropdownIcon = document.querySelector('.my-select .mat-select-arrow-wrapper')
dropdownIcon .style.transform =  'rotate(180deg)';
```

**when the dropdown state is close do this:**

```
dropdownIcon.style.transform =  'rotate(0deg)';
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide a fix for the "clear icon. I would also like to have the arrows shown on my pictures and not the default ones